# Sharepoint 2013 Dashboard Designer Connectivity Issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, performancepoint

My environment is 
SP 2013,
Windows server 2012 R2 and 
SQL 2014

I set up "PerformancePoint Services" following the youtube video : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2eQwMDTx1w"

When I try to connect from Dashboard designer, I get following error.
I have made "unattended" account "sysadmin" in SQL database.

[image]

ULS Viewer shows following error.

> The Unattended Service Account "***\unattended" does not have access to the following data source server.  Data source location: http://172.24.60.211/sites/dashboard/Data Connections/5_.000 Data source name: New Data Source Server name: http://172.24.60.211/sites/LegalDocs  Exception details: System.ArgumentException: The integrated security 'Sspi' is not supported for HTTP or HTTPS connections.
>    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ConnectionInfo.SetConnectionString(String cs)
>    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>    at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.DataSourceProviders.AdomdConnectionPool`1.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2()

What could be the reason ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the PerformancePoint unattended service account has permission to the SQL Server instance where the database exists or the database itself.

f you are connecting up to a SSAS cube, you need to make sure the PerformancePoint unattended service has access to the cube and the underlying data warehouse.

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2010/05/03/bi-center-and-data-connection-errors-when-using-performancepoint-dashboard-designer/